# Include fragments of HTML code using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS

Could we do something like

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'body.php'; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Where I am planning to reuse the code of header and footer instead of redundant headers and footer code on almost 30 pages.

I initially tried to use

```
<div ng-include="'fragment1.html'"></div>
```

What is the good practise to handle this scenario on the client side technologies? Or should I use server side coding to achieve this?

I do not want to use Ajax to load HTML as this would be http request and is always expensive from performance / loading speed perspective.

Comment: You should learn how to set up a simple web server on your dev machine.  If you continue loading your websites from `file:///` URLs, you will encounter endless headaches.  **EDIT:** You have removed the error message from your question, which makes my comment look out of place.  It also makes your `ng-include` snippet seem less relevant.

Comment: use ng-include.. it should work..run it in local server

Comment: http request and not always expensive, and if it saves 51% of your users from loading twice as much as needed, it saves time and bandwidth. i would recommend using a router instead of lots of pages.